# I can't seem to get Blender 4.0.1 to be used as my default version

Tags: interface, blend-files, settings

When I try to set Blender 4.0.1 to be used as my default Blender for opening files it keeps opening 3.6.5. The setting in preferences looks different now clicking "Register" doesn't seem to do anything files are still being opened with 3.6.5.

The "Make Default" button is gone

[image: blender 4.0.1 setting]
[image: blender 3.6.5 setting]

Comment: Just a thought. When you tried the Register button, did you also try it with the For All Users box clicked?

Comment: Are you on Windows? First of all I would definitely try to enable _For All Users_ as @curious_1 mentioned, then _Unregister_ and _Register_ again. If this does not work, go into the Windows Explorer, right-click on a *.blend file and select _Open With > _Choose another app_. My Explorer shows me as defaults "Blender" and "Blender 4.0". Select "Blender 4.0" and tick the _Always use this app to open .blend files_ option, then hit OK. At least on my computer this works.

Comment: It might also be worth right-clicking on your Blender icon and selecting "Run as Administrator" before choosing that setting. You should only need to run it as administrator once though.

Comment: Having now tried it, I can confirm that this doesn't appear to work! I have four versions of Blender installed with 3.6.8 currently set as the default. Trying to change that to 4.02 doesn't work whatever method I use to try to change it!

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I've tried registering will "all users" selected and no change, I'm also noticing that this only seems to be happening on my home PC which uses Win10 but my work PC uses Win11 and I'm not having this issue maybe it has something to do with the OS?

Comment: Well, I don't really know. I can only tell that I had this problem in the past with multiple versions of Blender installed, I'm not sure how I got it to work correct. But I fear it is not a Blender problem. I have two versions of Outlook for example and it is impossible to make Windows use the one I want as default. For Blender I could only suggest to de-install all older versions from Windows, then download an older one you want as zip file which you can launch from the extracted folder without installing it. (I cannot do something like that with my Outlook unfortunately, I wish I could.)

Comment: To add to the confusion, I'm using Windows 10. I just started up 4.0.2 as administrator. I clicked on the Register button and now any .blend file I click on opens with 4.0.2. I did not click on the For All Users option. Previously 3.6.8 was the default. Also I had a couple of .blend files on the desktop and they now display a thumbnail of them. My .blend files on another drive still display the Blender icon.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm also using Windows 10 (Professional).

Comment: In case it matters I have Windows 10 Home.